# How to retrieve a file's share mode?

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi

I've opened a file with [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) and set the `dwShareMode` parameter to `0` (no sharing).

I could try and create a the file again and use `GetLastError` to check the failure, but is there a method where this can be queried similar to `GetFileAttributesExW`?

Comment: There is no user mode API function or even NT `FileInformationClass` to query the current share-access state of a kernel file object or the filesystem's overall [`SHARE_ACCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-iocheckshareaccess) for the file. The per-open access state is available to drivers on the [file object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object) as `ReadAccess`, `WriteAccess`, `DeleteAccess`, `SharedRead`, `SharedWrite`, and `SharedDelete`.

Comment: Sysinternals Process Explorer installs a driver in order to report the RWD share access in the list of file handles for a process.

Comment: Isn't it easier to remember what share mode you used when you opened the file?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan For me, yes. For the purpose of this program to notify the user if they are trying to open a file another user that opened it with the same program, no.

Comment: @ErykSun So if `f1` is a file in a program opened as described, and on the next line `f2` is a file thats attempting to be opened for reading, how does the OS resolve that the path given to `f1` is not allowed to be shared? As I read your first comment, those attributes are available on the file object (`f1` instance), but that is not passed to `CreateFileW` for `f2` creation. Somewhere the information regarding the object `f1` points to is being stored for later checks. Additionally, what did you mean by "NT"? My Windows API/architecture knowledge is limited.

Comment: For that scenario, if `GetLastFile` error tells you that there is a sharing error, report that. It doesn't make sense to try to query this before you attempt to open the file anyway, because that just leads to a race condition. In other words, I think you are trying to repeat an action performed by the system anyway, and not only is that wasteful, it can't actually be done properly, because of the race.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That is a valid point; did you mean `GetLastError`?

Comment: The `SHARE_ACCESS` record in the filesystem's file control block (FCB) for the file is used to count the number of times a file has been opened with read, write, or delete access versus the number of times that read, write, or delete access has been shared. If a new open isn't compatible with existing opens when the filesystem calls [`IoCheckShareAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-iocheckshareaccess), the `IRP_MJ_CREATE` request fails with `STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION`.

Comment: Along similar lines, there is no way to query information about the [`FILE_LOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/file-lock) in a file's FCB that's used for per-process byte-range locking (similar to Unix file locking). Just try `ReadFile` or `WriteFile` and handle `ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION` if the range or part of the range is locked by a particular process/file-object tuple.

Comment: Note that, despite wide-spread misunderstanding, read-write-delete access sharing is associated with just opens of the filesystem file, not with processes, so a handle for a file can be inherited by a child process or duplicated to another process without leading to a sharing violation. But read-write access *locking* is limited to a particular process and file combination, so a handle for a file with byte-range locks cannot be inherited by a child process or duplicated to another process without leading to a potential locking violation.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean `GetLastError`

Comment: @ErykSun Not sure I follow wrt the read-write-delete access across processes. I created a file with no sharing in one process and then attempted to create a file with `FILE_SHARE_READ` in another and received `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. Perhaps I am misunderstanding our point?

Comment: The `SHARE_ACCESS` record in the file's FCB doesn't record anything about which processes have access. So if you try to re-open the file in the same process, even with the same access, you'll get a sharing violation if the requested sharing mode isn't compatible. However, the handle for the file object can be duplicated to or inherited by another process, and it will work fine. OTOH, byte-range locks are associated with a (process, file object) tuple, so duplicating or inheriting the handle for the file object to another process will not grant that process access to the locked byte range.